# Ruby on Rails Params comparing not working in If else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements

I ran into a very strange problem . I am trying to use if and else in rails it works perfect when I am comparing current_user.id with numbers but when I am trying to do it with params it did not work . Here is my code which work :

```
<%= @u = 2 %>

   <% if current_user.id == @u %>
   ssssss
   <% else %> 
  aaaaaaaaa
   <% end  %>
```

And when I am trying to use this code :

```
 <%= @u = params[:id] %>

   <% if current_user.id == @u %>
   ssssss
   <% else %> 
  aaaaaaaaa
   <% end  %>
```

It is always giving me  aaaaaaaaa value it would be helpful if anyone can help me to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are trying to compare string with number . Above answer is sufficient but I would like to correct your code simply add this to your code and you are done :

```
  <%= @u = 2 %>
    <% if current_user.id == @u.to_i %>
           ssssss
           <% else %> 
          aaaaaaaaa
           <% end  %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `current_user.id == @u.to_i` rather then `@u` because params gets a string and you compare with an integer.

Or you can compare by using `current_user.id.to_s == @u`

Comment: @WandMaker No, it should be `to_s` because current_user.id is type integer, which is being compared to `params[:id]` (through `@u`), which is type string. If you use `to_i` you're not casting anything because `current_user.id` is already integer.

Comment: @MarsAtomic My comment was pointing to potential typo in answer `@u.t_i`

Comment: @WandMaker is right you provided two options but on the first option you have a typo and should be .to_i

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer has been given. I usually, in cases like this, like to output the variables I'm interested in with ".inspect". This usually gives a clear information about what goes wrong.

In your specific case, this would have output `3` for the id and `"3"` for the param - easy to see that way.